# Unable to install vscode-ripgrep on Docker: Unexpected token "..." in "...url.parse(_url)"

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg, theia

I need to setup a theia environment on Docker (ubuntu 18.04 container). During the installation using the docker file, I need to install vscode-ripgrep since it is a dependency for 2 theia modules:

@theia/file-search

@theia/search-in-workspace

However, I get the following error:
[image: error]

I went through multiple issues on GitHub and StackOverflow, but cannot find one that will fix my problem.

I also tried to install vscode-ripgrep on my host machine (also ubuntu) and it worked. I guess I am missing some dependencies in the Dockerfile. However, I went through theia's GitHub page and installed all the common dependencies (https://github.com/theia-ide/theia-apps/blob/master/theia-full-docker/Dockerfile).

The previous OS kernel lab teacher used the exact Dockerfile and it did work about 3-4 months ago. I guess that dependencies changes made a breaking change.

Here is the Dockerfile that I have:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN rm /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl binutils python make build-essential \
                       man manpages-posix manpages-posix-dev glibc-doc \
                       python3 less locales libx11-dev libxkbfile-dev snapd
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install curl xz-utils wget gpg

#Install node and yarn
#From: https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/6b8d86d6ad59e0d1e7a94cec2e909cad137a028f/8/Dockerfile

# gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node#release-keys
RUN set -ex \
    && for key in \
    4ED778F539E3634C779C87C6D7062848A1AB005C \
    B9E2F5981AA6E0CD28160D9FF13993A75599653C \
    94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
    B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
    77984A986EBC2AA786BC0F66B01FBB92821C587A \
    71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
    FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
    8FCCA13FEF1D0C2E91008E09770F7A9A5AE15600 \
    C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
    DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
    A48C2BEE680E841632CD4E44F07496B3EB3C1762 \
    ; do \
    gpg --batch --keyserver ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --batch --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --batch --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --batch --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --batch --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" ; \
    done

ARG NODE_VERSION=8.0.0
ENV NODE_VERSION $NODE_VERSION

RUN ARCH= && dpkgArch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \
    && case "${dpkgArch##*-}" in \
    amd64) ARCH='x64';; \
    ppc64el) ARCH='ppc64le';; \
    s390x) ARCH='s390x';; \
    arm64) ARCH='arm64';; \
    armhf) ARCH='armv7l';; \
    i386) ARCH='x86';; \
    *) echo "unsupported architecture"; exit 1 ;; \
    esac \
    && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" \
    && curl -SLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
    && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
    && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner \
    && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt \
    && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs

ENV YARN_VERSION 1.13.0

RUN set -ex \
    && for key in \
    6A010C5166006599AA17F08146C2130DFD2497F5 \
    ; do \
    gpg --batch --keyserver ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --batch --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --batch --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --batch --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --batch --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" ; \
    done \
    && curl -fSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz" \
    && curl -fSLO --compressed "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc" \
    && gpg --batch --verify yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && mkdir -p /opt/yarn \
    && tar -xzf yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz -C /opt/yarn --strip-components=1 \
    && ln -s /opt/yarn/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn \
    && ln -s /opt/yarn/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg \
    && rm yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz.asc yarn-v$YARN_VERSION.tar.gz

#Developer tools

## Git and sudo (sudo needed for user override)
RUN apt-get -y install git sudo

RUN locale-gen fr_CA.UTF-8
RUN update-locale LANG=fr_CA.UTF-8
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 8.0.0
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
ENV SHELL /bin/bash
ENV PAGER less

# Install nvm with node and npm
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.30.1/install.sh | bash \
    && source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH
RUN npm install -g yarn

# Create fake clangd
RUN ln -s /bin/false /usr/bin/clangd

# Create user directory
RUN useradd -u 3000 --create-home student
RUN npm install vscode-ripgrep
COPY package.json package.json


# Switch to new user
WORKDIR /home/student
USER student

# Build Theia
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn && yarn theia build

# Create Theia directory and change cd alias
RUN echo "alias cd='HOME=~/workspace cd'" >> .bashrc

# Let's try to reduce memory footprint...
CMD yarn theia start workspace --hostname 0.0.0.0 --port 3000
```

Thanks for the help and have a nice day!

Vittorio